# com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource at ... (Unknown Source)

Tags: java, maven, jsp, java-web-start, openmrs

jnpl error is

> Unable to launch application Location: http://localhost:8080
>   Component:
>   http://localhost:8080/openmrs/moduleResources/muzimabiometrics/Scanner.jar
>   Reason: unable to load resource

Below is the jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <jnlp spec="1.0+"    codebase="http://localhost:8080/openmrs/moduleResources/muzimabiometrics/"    href=""> <information>    <title>Web start</title>    <vendor>Muzima Team</vendor>    <offline-allowed/> </information> <resources>    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>    <jar href="scanner.jar" main="true"/>    <jar href="Jlibfprint.jar" />    <jar href="httpcore-4.4.4.jar" />    <jar href="httpclient-4.5.2.jar" />    <jar href="commons-logging-1.2.jar" />    <jar href="commons-codec-1.9.jar" /> </resources>    <security>
       <all-permissions/>    </security> <application-desc main-class="org.openmrs.module.muzimabiometrics.ScanFingerprint">    </application-desc> <update check="background"/> </jnlp>
```

Comment: Might want to actually add the file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/openmrs/moduleResources/muzimabiometrics/" href="">
<information>
    <title>Web start</title>
    <vendor>Muzima Team</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="scanner.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="Jlibfprint.jar" />
    <jar href="httpcore-4.4.4.jar" />
    <jar href="httpclient-4.5.2.jar" />
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.2.jar" />
    <jar href="commons-codec-1.9.jar" />

Comment: i am new to this platform and adding a file is a bit hard, that is the starting of the jnlp file

Comment: @enocktum Add your code in the comment above to your actual question. Not in the comments.